# Swift UI remove space between list rows

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a list with `forEach` in it that is displaying rows whit a little space between them and I am unable to remove this space. (the view inside for each has the yellow border)

[image]

Here is the code:

```
VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            List {
                ForEach(self.viewModel.notifications, id: \.self) { nameDay in
                    NotificationViewListCell(day: nameDay).border(.yellow).listRowSeparator(.hidden).listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                }.onDelete(perform: delete(at:))
            }.listStyle(.plain).border(.red)
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: CGFloat(self.viewModel.notifications.count * 44))
}
```

I have tried to use `listRowSeparator` like I found in another answer but it seems to do nothing with the top and bottom row spacing. I also would like to use the `.plain` style of the row

Is there some way how to remove this row spacing between the yellow rectangles?

Comment: Seems that your NotificationViewListCell is smaller than the row.

Comment: @MartaPaniti yeah, the thing is I want the row to be so small, but I have fixed that with the environment variable for the list view

Comment: Just post the solution, maybe it will helps others :)